# How to write a trigger function to Jquery trigger()

Tags: jquery, triggers, callback

I have a line of code as follows:

```
$('#type').val(target).trigger('change');
```

It opens a new div(it was `display none`). I want to run a code after that div opens and locates at DOM. How ca I do that?

Comment: I'm *guessing* from your question that the `div` is shown in response to the `change` event. If the `div` was `display: none` and all you're doing is showing it, it's *already* in the DOM tree. It should appear near instantaneously, no need to wait. If my guess is incorrect, the question needs (much) more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a function to the event and execute it like so:

```
$('#type').val(target).trigger('change', function() {
//do something
});

//in your event
$('#type').change(function(event, func) {
       //do things
       if(func) {
          func();
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event listener on that trigger just like you would any other native jQuery event.

```
//You can trigger it like you usually do or optionally pass in extra parameters in case you want your subscribed listeners to have access to that info
$('#type').val(target).trigger('change', param1, param2);

$('#type').live("change", function(event, param1, param2) {
       $("#myDiv").show();
});
```